# Reachability graphic overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

The app I'm writing depends on having a network connection (both to the internet in general and to a specific host). The app works completely offline but the user needs to know it's offline.

I am using Reachability to watch for changes to the connection.

I was thinking of using a traffic light type system...

- Red = no connection to the internet.
- Yellow = connection to the internet but no connection to the host.
- Green = connection to host.

At the moment I am changing the tint colour of the UINavigationBar (until I can get something better). I was thinking of putting a coloured circle into the UIStatusBar to show red, yellow, green but I'm not sure if this is possible?

I don't want to hide anything on the status bar, just add my own graphic.

Is that possible? Could anyone explain how to do this? Or is there a better way of doing this that anyone could suggest?

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the UX site. I've added a question there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add anything to the status bar, however this project may be of interest to you: https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay and this question and it's answers: [Write some text in (or on) UIStatusBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328664/write-some-text-in-or-on-uistatusbar)